# Content-Type: application/pdf changing to Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Tags: node.js, api, rest, restify

I have a GET Http request as below

```
const getData = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    .... some code...
    const response = await createPdfResponse(location);
    res.setHeader("Accept", "application/pdf");
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    res.setHeader(
      "Content-Disposition",
      "inline; filename=fileName.pdf"
    );

    res.send(200, response);
  } catch (error) {
    const errorBody = error.body;
    const statusCode = error.code;
    res.send(statusCode, { errorBody });
  }
};
```

When I am getting the response, it comes with Content-Type: application/octet-stream.

I need Content-Type: application/pdf.

Can someone please help me with this? I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: When you make this request from a browser, does your PDF not download/display as expected? Or does it work fine, and the only issue is that the header is not what you're expecting?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. This is caused by resitify code:

https://github.com/restify/node-restify/blob/master/lib/response.js#L477

Just use `res.sendRaw(200, response)`